# JQuery Efficiency Need to make my Code Better and Learn

Tags: jquery, performance

I have the below code and it does what I want but i know it is a bad way to right it.  How could I accomplish the same thing without having to duplicate the code for each set of items.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#plink-1').click(function() {
    $('.active').slideUp().removeClass('active');
    $('#pshow-1').slideToggle().addClass('active');
});
$('#plink-2').click(function() {
    $('.active').slideUp().removeClass('active');
    $('#pshow-2').slideToggle().addClass('active');
});
$('#plink-3').click(function() {
    $('.active').slideUp().removeClass('active');
    $('#pshow-3').slideToggle().addClass('active');
});
$('#plink-4').click(function() {
    $('.active').slideUp().removeClass('active');
    $('#pshow-4').slideToggle().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#plink-1, #plink-2, #plink-3, #plink-4').click(function() {
    var index = this.id.replace('plink-','');  // will give you ->  1,2,..
    $('.active').slideUp().removeClass('active');
    $('#pshow-' + index).slideToggle().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('a[id^="plink-"]').click(function() {
    $('.active').slideUp().removeClass('active');
    $('#pshow-' + $(this).prop('id').replace('plink-','')).slideToggle().addClass('active');   
})
```

using this code you will not need to update your jquery code when adding or removing plinks

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the great answers, you got my head in the right direction.  I ended up using the following function based on what i had created in my CSS. still tweaking some of the animation etc but it is working well.  Thanks!

```
$('.pitem a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 150);
        $('#portfolios').find('.active').fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
        $('#portfolios').find('#pshow-'+i).fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
    });
});
```